# How to check if words can be created from list of letters?

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, words

I have a string `$raw="aabbcdfghmnejaachto"` and  an array `$word_array=array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg')`.

My program needs to check whether it is possible to make the words in the array with letters from the string. There is one extra condition; if the word contains a letter occurring more than once, that letter must occur at least the same number of times in the string.

E.g. `egg`. There are two `g`'s. If the string `$raw` doesn't contain two `g`'s, then it's not possible to make this word.

This is my expected result:

```
Array([cat]=>'Yes',[rat]=>'No',[goat]=>'Yes',[total]=>'No',[egg]=>'No')
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't output the expected result:

```
$res=array();
$raw="aabbcdfghmnejaachto";
$word_array=array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg');
$raw_array= str_split($raw);
foreach($word_array as $word=>$value)
{
    $word_value= str_split($value);
    foreach($word_value as $w=>$w_value)
    {
        foreach($raw_array as $raw=>$raw_value)
        {
            if(strcmp($w_value,$raw_value)==0)
            {
                $res[$value]='Yes';
            }
            else
            {
                $res[$value]='No';
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

---

**EDIT:** The code, as originally posted, was missing the letter `e` from the string `$raw` so the `egg` example would actually return `No`. I have updated the Question and all the Answers to reflect this. - [robinCTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961728/robincts)

Comment: what you actually need.?

Comment: output like  Array([cat]=>'Yes',[egg]=>no,[goat]=>yes....)

Comment: please read above description

Comment: if string not contain word then output should like Array([cat]=>'Yes',[egg]=>no,[goat]=>yes,[mongo]=>no

Comment: Your inconsitent indentation makes this question **really** hard to read

Comment: @user7441072, I have added answer and it's working for all occurrences! Please check.

Comment: Please don't modify the originally posted code unless you made a typo. If you've tried something new and it still doesn't work, add a new code block to the original question. If you've solved the problem, either add it as a new code block (if you solved it yourself), post it as an answer (if you based it off a posted answer), or do nothing but accept the best *correct* answer.

Comment: @FKEinternet Fixed it for you ;)

Comment: @robinCTS Thanks! :)

Comment: This is a rare, great question and a thoughtful task.  A clear, focussed question with minimum relevant sample data, coding attempt, and expected output.  If only all questions on SO were this good!  A well earned +1 from me.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sigh. Check out the edit history though! But you are right. The core was originally there. That's why a spent a bit of time polishing it up.

Comment: @robinCTS good on you too then. (can't upvote your contributions, nor can mine be upvoted -- we can just be proud knowing we helped SO and others)  ... I guess we get _some_ credit for edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You must loop through each word/element in the `$words` array, then loop again through each character of each word.
- Upon each iteration of the outer loop, set the default result value to `Yes`.
- Then you must iterate each unique character of the current word. (`array_count_values()`)
- Check if the number of occurrences of the current character in the word is greater than the number of occurrences of the current character in the string of letters.

*As a matter of performance optimization, `array_count_values()` is used on the inner loop to avoid any unnecessary iterations of duplicate letters in `$word`.  The `$count` variable saves having to make two `substr_count()` calls in the if statement.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b19116251aba1322c479d1831cf98405c765415a))

```
$string = "aabbcdfghmnejaachto";
$words = array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg');
foreach ($words as $word) {  // iterate each word
    $result[$word]='Yes';  // set default result value
    foreach (array_count_values(str_split($word)) as $char=>$count) {  // iterate each unique letter in word
        if ($count > substr_count($string, $char)) {  // compare current char's count vs same char's count in $string
            $result[$word]='No';  // if more of the character in word than available in $string, set No
            break;  // make early exit from inner loop, to avoid unnecessary iterations
        }
    }    
}
var_export($result);
```

This is the output :

```
array (
  'cat' => 'Yes',
  'rat' => 'No',
  'goat' => 'Yes',
  'total' => 'No',
  'egg' => 'No',
)
```

---

**BIG THANKYOU** to [mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) for <s>hijacking</s> significantly enhancing this answer.

Comment: Up voted! Intelligent answer of the question! :) Should be selected as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are not counting the number of times each character occurs in the `$raw` array, you are just checking each character in each of the words to see if that character exists in `$raw`. Unless you put in some form of counting, or else make a copy of `$raw` for each word and remove letters as they are used, you are not going to be able to do this.

Comment: This is not much of an answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa I agree, but at least I identified the problem even though I was too tired to write the code.  Cppi Khatri wrote out the solution, so the OP got what they were looking for, in the end.

Comment: @user7441072 Thanks, I appreciate that.  I'm glad Cppi Khatri was less tired than me :) and that you got your working code :)

Answer (score 2):

I have counted occurrences of characters in string and compare that number of occurrence! You can find this answer working!!!

```
$res=array();
$raw="aabbcdfghmnejaachto"; //tgrel -- to make all yes
$res=array();
$word_array=array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg');
$raw_array= str_split($raw);
$count_raw = array_count_values($raw_array);

foreach($word_array as $value)
{
    $word_value= str_split($value);
    $newArray = array_count_values($word_value);
    $res[$value]='yes';
    foreach($newArray as $char=>$number){
        if(!isset($count_raw[$char]) || $count_raw[$char]<$number){
            $res[$value]='No';
            break;
        }
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: a `break` after `$res[$value]='No'` would make this snippet better, but it is not better than yoeunes' answer.

Comment: Thanks for complements! I appreciate Yoeunces's answer and up voted!! :)

Comment: This works, but you should add a bit of documentation explaining what you added and why your code is different.  I basically did that for you in my comment supporting your answer.  ;)

Comment: Thanks @gview! :) yoeunes' answer is just like enhancement of my answer, so I feel not to explain in documentation and I am happy his answer is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Your error here is obvious, that you decided whether a value a word is accepted or not on individual tests of characters, while it should be based on the all the letter of the word , you don't need to precise both the key and value of an array if you need only its value
as in

```
foreach($word_array as $value)
```

then I've found that the use of the function [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), make the code much clearer

```
$res=array();
$raw="aabbcdfghmnejaachto";
$res=array();
$word_array=array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg');
$raw_array= str_split($raw);

foreach($word_array as $value)
{
    $word_value= str_split($value);
    $res[$value]='yes';
    foreach($word_value as $w_value)
    {
        if (!in_array($w_value,$raw_array))
            $res[$value]='No';

    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Comment: @user7441072, yes

Comment: Thanks, i forgot in_array function that time, it was my interview question yesterday. they gave 45 minutes. but i got tension and confused. i didnt reached correct answer,so i got rejected for that firm :( :(

Comment: @user7441072, wish you a better luck next time

Comment: :( my health condition was also not right, i went with blood pressure 60/100 and fever. only me knows :)

Comment: Why did you accept this answer.  This code does not work to your specifications.  See this:  https://3v4l.org/BjnKX   It doesn't deal with words that contain a certain count of letters.

Comment: I found this code partially working! If I add "lre" to `$raw` I can find all as Yes, Which is totally wrong. total and egg must be 'No'! I am with @gview

Comment: @gview, ok i un marked answer,you know exact solution?

Comment: You can accept @Shaunak's answer.  As you can see, he utilizes the function array_count_values to get an array indexed with each letter and with an associated count.  The comparison then takes into account both the existence of a letter, and the count of that letter required.

Comment: I just noticed the other answer from @yoeunes.  That is a nice approach as well.  But in each case, they should provide you some insight into how their code works for these answers to be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to make it w/o loops, but with closures:

```
$raw = "aabbcdfghmnejaachto";
$word_array = ['cat', 'rat', 'goat', 'total', 'egg'];

$result = [];
$map = count_chars($raw, 1);
array_walk(
    $word_array,
    function ($word) use ($map, &$result) {
        $result[$word] = !array_udiff_assoc(
            count_chars($word, 1), $map, function ($i, $j) { return $i > $j; }
        ) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }
);
```

1. We are building a map of symbols, used in original string with `count_chars($raw, 1)`, so it will look like this.

`$map:`

```
[
    97 => 4, // "97" is a code for "a"; and "4" - occurrence number.
    98 => 2,
    ...
]
```

2. `array_walk` goes through words and adds each of them in a final `$result` with a `Yes` or `No` values that come from a comparison with a map, that was built for a word.
3. `array_udiff_assoc` compares two maps, throwing away those elements that have the same key and values bigger for an original map (comparing with a map for a word). Also *array_udiff_assoc() returns an array containing all the values from array1 that are not present in any of the other arguments*, so the final step is a negation operation preceding `array_udiff_assoc`.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75979fc6c39ac097b0690900d832bd3834f51ec7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$res=array();
$word_array=array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg');
$raw="aabbcrdfghmnejaachtol";
foreach($word_array as $word=>$value)
{
    $raw_array= str_split($raw);
    $res[$value]='Yes';
    $word_value= str_split($value);
    foreach($word_value as $w=>$w_value)
    {
        if(!in_array($w_value,$raw_array))
        {
             $res[$value]='No';
        }
        else
        {
            unset($raw_array[array_search($w_value, $raw_array)]);
        }
    }
}
```

This will not allow character again, if it is used once Like "total".

Comment: @user7441072 This answer does not use best practice because it unnecessarily overwrites static data on each iteration and there is no `break` for an early loop exit -- wasted iterations.  This should not wear the green tick and should not be what you use in your project.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa for explaining as i also know that but this is the solution which is asked in question.

Comment: It would be good if you can put `$raw="aabbcdfghmnjaachtol";
        $raw_array= str_split($raw);` outside the loop!!

Comment: @ Shaunak Shukla, i am using "unset" to remove the character, which is used once.So when it will check for the next word. its will check by left string after unset.

Comment: @CppiKhatri Are you blaming the OP for the inefficiencies in the method that you wrote?  We are all responsible for the quality of our own work.  There are usually multiple ways to write a "correct answer" for programming questions, the skill is in finding the "best" way to write it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am not blaming OP for post.Please share best answer.if that will be more efficient.Hope, will be marked as green tick.

Comment: @CppiKhatri What you want to do is put the `$raw="aabbcdfghmnjaachtol";` assignment outside of the loop - there's no need to do that every time, the string remains fixed.  However, as you've correctly written, the `$raw_array` assignment *does* need to be *inside* the loop.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks @FKEinternet. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @robinCTS,actually what happend?

Comment: @user7441072 (& @CppiKhatri) Lots of people editing lots of posts at the same time causes lots of problems ;)

Comment: @robin. haha what problem happend now? everybody happy  no?

Comment: @user7441072Your question is really good and have good logic. Thats why its causing. No issue bro. Let it be. Its good to correct which is. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can check to see if each letter from each word is within the letters given, and pluck found letters out as we go.

The function below short circuits if a letter is not found.

```
<?php
function can_form_word_from_letters($word, $letters) {
    $letters      = str_split($letters);
    $word_letters = str_split($word);
    foreach($word_letters as $letter) {
        $key = array_search($letter, $letters);
        if($key === false) return;
        unset($letters[$key]); // Letter found, now remove it from letters.
    }
    return true;
}

$letters = "aabbcdfghmnejaachto";
$words   = array('cat','rat','goat','total','egg');

foreach($words as $word) {
    $result[$word] = can_form_word_from_letters($word, $letters) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
  'cat' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
  'rat' => string 'No' (length=2)
  'goat' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
  'total' => string 'No' (length=2)
  'egg' => string 'No' (length=2)
```